# Firefox doesn't show option to use camera as file upload

Tags: forms, firefox, android-camera

I am creating a form in Microsoft Forms that has the option to add an image, taken using the camera app at the moment of filling in the form. I am using Firefox to fill in the form as Firefox has the option to open links in private by default, which is essential for me.

I have given Firefox access to my camera, both in the device settings as well as the browser settings. However, when I click "Upload file" it automatically takes me to my internal storage, rather than asking if I want to use my storage or use the camera app. I have followed the same steps in Chrome and there, it is working. There, after pressing "Upload file" it shows you the prompt to "Choose an action" where you will see the option to either open the Camera app or to open your folders. This is exactly what I need, but in Firefox

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Running into the same issue.